# remove the duplicate objects in list of objects without using any looping statements

Tags: c#, list, duplicates

I am trying remove the duplicate objects in list of objects based on the ID prpoerty
**List with Duplicate entry**

```
[
    {
        "Id": 2,
        "Question": "skill profile",
        "Answer": "answer2"
    },
    {
        "Id": 6,
        "Question": "skill profile",
        "Answer": "skill profile"
    },
    {
        "Id": 7,
        "Question": "skill profile",
        "Answer": "answer7"
    },
    {
        "Id": 6,
        "Question": "skill profile",
        "Answer": "skill profile"
    },
    {
        "Id": 8,
        "Question": "question8",
        "Answer": "skill profile"
    }
]
```

```
list.GroupBy(x => x.Id).Select(d => d.Distinct()).ToList();
```

Expected Output:

```
[
{
    "Id": 2,
    "Question": "skill profile",
    "Answer": "answer2"
},
{
    "Id": 6,
    "Question": "skill profile",
    "Answer": "skill profile"
},
{
    "Id": 7,
    "Question": "skill profile",
    "Answer": "answer7"
},
{
    "Id": 8,
    "Question": "question8",
    "Answer": "skill profile"
}
```

]

I tried the group by option but it didn't worked
Please anyone help me with this

Comment: " tried the group by option but i didn't worked" - so what exactly happened, vs what you expected to happen? (It would be ideal if you'd provide a [mcve] with actual output and expected output...)

Comment: The Distinct after the GroupBy does not makes Sense. Try First() instead. Meaning you want to select the first object of each group.

Comment: yes, Tried using the first also but still the duplicate entry of id : 6 is present

Comment: Perhaps have a look at [`.DistinctBy()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinctby?view=net-7.0)

Comment: Oh, I think i get It, It wasn't clear what you really wanted inspite the title, would be better If you showed the expected output. Try list.GroupBy(x => x.Id).Where(x=> x.Count() ==1).Select(x=>x.First()).ToList()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
var result = list.GroupBy(x => x.Id).Select(x => x.First()).ToList();
```

If you are using .NET 6 or above, you can use [DistinctBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinctby?view=net-8.0)

```
var result =  list.DistinctBy(i => i.Id).ToList();
```